# Delay task and return empty value if delay time exceeded

Tags: c#, .net, delay

How can I delay a task until a variable's value is returned and if the the delay time is exceeded, the variable's value returned null. For example:

```
TaskA.Delay(5000);

if variable not equal to empty string
continue with Task A

else
if delay time not exceeded yet

continue running the current task
else

set variable's value to empty string
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is this variable? Who changes its value? Where is the task that you want to delay?

Comment: Either run it on separate thread and kill it if it exceeds time, or if you can check time often in where you are obtaining your variable. It all depends on what you need this for.

Comment: @Claudius Threading? Why would you bring up a whole new thread for something so simple. What if the task can't be run on a separate thread? What if you need to do thousands of these concurrently using non-blocking I/O (hint a thread uses ~1MB of Ram, 1000 threads would use up over 1GB of Ram).

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to start a "delay" task, and run it concurrently with your "real" task and see which one finishes first:

```
public async Task<int?> ValueOrNull( )
{
  var task = SomeAsyncMethod() //--> the work to wait on
  var timeout = Task.Delay( new TimeSpan( 0,0,5 ) );
  var first = await Task.WhenAny( task, timeout );
  if ( first == timeout ) return null;
  await first;  //--> It's already done, but let it throw any exception here
  return;
}
```

You could generalize this by passing your task and timeout in:

```
public async Task<T> ValueOrNull( Task<T> task, TimeSpan patience )
{
  var timeout = Task.Delay( patience );
  var first = await Task.WhenAny( task, timeout );
  if ( first == timeout ) return default( T );
  await first;  //--> It's already done, but let it throw any exception here
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to implement Clay's method.

```
public Task<int?> ValueOrNull( )
{
    return Task.WhenAny(
        SomeAsyncMethod(),
        DelayResult(default(int?), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    );
}

public async Task<T> DelayResult<T>(T result, TimeSpan delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    return result;
}
```